# Measure theory exercise wrong?

Tags: measure-theory

**Prove that for every $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ , there exists a there exists a $G\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$G\supset E$ and $\mu^*_l(E)=\mu^*_l(G)$** ($G is G_\delta$)
[image]

How can $G\supset E$ and $\mu^*_l(E)=\mu^*_l(G)$? It seems a contradiction. I guess this exercise is wrong once the for $\mu^*_l(E)=\mu^*_l(G)$ it cannot be G but its intersection, that would approach E. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther is nothing wrong with the exercise. It looks like you don't understand null sets.

For a concrete silly  example, you can have  $E=(0,1) $, and $G=[0,1] $.

Comment: Could you expand your answer? How is the length of $E=(0,1)$ and $G=[0,1]$ the same?

Comment: You think they are different? What do you think they are?

Comment: My intuition tells me the length must be different once $E$ does not contain the points and $G$ does. However the difference between $\mu(E)$ and $\mu(G)$ would be tiny let´s say less or equal than an $\epsilon >0$

Comment: But this is a concrete question. I assume you will agree that the length of $[0,1]$ is $1$. What do you think the length of $(0,1)$ is?

Comment: less than 1 because it is open

Comment: "Less than one" is not a number. Try to imagine how much "less than one" it could be. Think of how long is $[0.1,0.9]$; how long is $[0.01,0.99]$; how long is $[0.001,0.999]$. Etc.

Comment: Even so it is not going to attain the width of the closed interval, right? Could you show me some proof of that claim?

Comment: The definition of open set that I studied is the following:$(\forall x\in X)(\exists\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}: B(x,\epsilon)\subset X)$

Comment: You seem to be missing the most basic points. The very definition of measure that you are using in your post is based on taking the length of an open interval $(a,b)$ to be $b- a$. But, even before this, think of the length of the closed intervals I mentioned above, and that those internals are inside $(0,1)$.